# VueJS : using Ckeditor AND Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, webpack, ckeditor, vuejs2

I'm working on an app using VueJS 2, vue-router, ckeditor and vue-ua (Google Analytics). All of them are installed via npm. I'm using webpack (It's a Laravel 5.3 app).

In a component, I'm calling ckeditor to display a WYSIWYG textarea. It works fine.

When I attach vue-ua to my router, Ckeditor triggers an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '17' of undefined
```

It's here :

```
keystrokeToString: function(a, g) {
    (...)
    d & CKEDITOR.CTRL && (c.push(h ? "⌘" : a[17]),
    (...)
```

It looks like the variable 'a' is replaced somewhere along the process, despite its scope, which should be local.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To find the source of that error you're going to have to walk through the calls to it, but honestly if it's breaking like this it could be the first of many...

Looking at the CKEditor repo it seems v4 didn't support webpack so I assume you're working with v5? There is a github post all about adding webpack support, but I'm not sure its complete yet: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/139

Perhaps it would be better to just detach CKEditor from your bundle. Calling a separate js file and referencing whatever Global param it attaches to the `window`.